# Devise can't redirect me to different page with subdomain after sign_in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, routes, devise, multi-tenant

I have rails app with apartment and devise. Everything works fine except signing in from [www.lvh.me/...](http://www.lvh.me/...), it should redirect me to user subdomain and it tries to do that but for whatever reason it doesn't get me anywhere and just leaves me on sign in page.

```
#trying to redirect me to root

Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2022-11-05 12:57:13 +0100
Processing by Users::SessionsController#create as TURBO_STREAM
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "user"=>{"email"=>"chris@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Log in"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "public"."users".* FROM "public"."users" WHERE "public"."users"."email" = $1 ORDER BY "public"."users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["email", "christ@gmail.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/Users/sessions_controller.rb:13:in `create'
Redirected to http://chris.lvh.me:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 207ms (ActiveRecord: 0.3ms | Allocations: 1479)

Started OPTIONS "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2022-11-05 12:57:13 +0100
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [OPTIONS] "/"):

#trying to redirect me to members_path

Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2022-11-05 13:02:06 +0100
Processing by Users::SessionsController#create as TURBO_STREAM
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "user"=>{"email"=>"christ@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Log in"}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "public"."users".* FROM "public"."users" WHERE "public"."users"."email" = $1 ORDER BY "public"."users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["email", "chris@gmail.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/Users/sessions_controller.rb:13:in `create'
Redirected to http://chris.lvh.me:3000/members
Completed 302 Found in 218ms (ActiveRecord: 3.2ms | Allocations: 5039)

Started OPTIONS "/members" for 127.0.0.1 at 2022-11-05 13:02:06 +0100 
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [OPTIONS] "/members"):
```

I have modified sessions_controller.rb that looks like this:

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  # before_action :configure_sign_in_params, only: [:create]

  # POST /resource/sign_in
  def create
    self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
    set_flash_message!(:notice, :signed_in)
    sign_in(resource_name, resource)
    yield resource if block_given?
    # respond_with resource, location: after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    redirect_to(members_url(subdomain: resource.subdomain) , allow_other_host: true)
  end
```

When I give browser the url by myself(with subdomain) routes work as they should.

```
#routes.rb
class SubdomainConstraint
  def self.matches?(request)
    subdomains = %w{ www admin }
    request.subdomain.present? && !subdomains.include?(request.subdomain)
  end
end

Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, controllers: {sessions: 'users/sessions', registrations: 'users/registrations'}
  # Define your application routes per the DSL in https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

  # Defines the root path route ("/")
  # root "articles#index"
  root "members#index"
  constraints SubdomainConstraint do
    resources :members
  end
end
```

Comment: I gave up in trying to make multitenant app with apartment. I highly recommend to use row-level approach.

Answer (score 0):

Probably in the views you should pass data: { turbo: false } for now because it seems it is redirecting but not doing anything on view, the same thing happened to me.

`<%= f.submit t('global.buttons.sign_up'), class: 'button full', data: { turbo: false } %>`